# How to update a site collection property bag with xml like data using powershell?

Tags: 2013, powershell, property-bag

I've tried this:

```
$spSite = Get-SPSite -Identity http://mysitecollectionUrl;
$spwWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb();    
$xmlFileContent = GetContent -Path ./myXmlFile.xml
$spwWeb.AllProperties["myPropertyBagKey"] = $xmlFileContent;    
$spwWeb.AllProperties.Update();
$spWWeb.Update();
```

After runing this snippet nothing is happening. No error, no update of the property bag's value.
When I'm trying to edit the property bag using the UI, it does not display the value inside the value preview in the list of property bag.
I'm pretty sure that there is something wrong when putting xml like data inside a property bag.

What is the proper way to do it ?

Comment: Apparently, there is limit 4 Ko for the value of a property bag. Any attempt to edit the value by adding content exceeding that size will fail.